# JavaFX AreaChart - doesn't color area below last points

Tags: java, charts, javafx-2, stacked-area-chart

Why doesn't AreaChart cover all the area below the line?

Here's the fxml code for my chart (it's really  basic):

```
<AreaChart fx:id="CWTareaLayerChart" prefHeight="547.0" prefWidth="682.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
    <xAxis>
        <NumberAxis side="BOTTOM" fx:id="xAxisCWT" />
    </xAxis>
    <yAxis>
        <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxisCWT" side="LEFT" />
    </yAxis>
</AreaChart>
```

I define the axis in Java Controller with @FXML tag.

The initialization part (this method is called from *public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)* :

```
private void initializeLayerChart() {
    xAxisCWT.setForceZeroInRange(false);
    yAxisCWT.setForceZeroInRange(true);

    xAxisCWT.setAutoRanging(true);
    yAxisCWT.setAutoRanging(true);

    yAxisCWT.setLowerBound(-5.0);

    xAxisCWT.setLabel("W (%)");
    yAxisCWT.setLabel("avg C (pF)");
}
```

There's also a Refresh button which refreshes the content of series (there can be one or more series) and re-draws the chart. The method itselfs returns *List < XYChart.Series >* and series contain Double values; then the series are added to chart:

```
this.CWTareaLayerChart.getData().addAll(allSeries);
```

As the result I obtain something like this:

[Two series on AreaChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcMFO.png)

or this:

[One serie on AreaChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg9ZA.png)

I've tried different combinations of true/false in setAutoRanging() and setForceZeroInRange(), also played with setLowerBound(), but the result is always something like on the images - the last points of series are shown but the area below isn't colored.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but I can't. Maybe your plot point data is the problem. How do you get the data for the plot points?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to set the `threshold` parameter?

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.threshold

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/w5f3Ltcu/

Comment: I'm not using highcharts library (which is used for javascript applications, if I googled it right) but javaFX. I suppose the alternative for your threshold parameter is exactly `setLowerBound()` function so yes, I tried it.